# Android Socket Error- >libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(Iobridge.java.114)

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

In the below code i am just creating a socket to run the Shell command in my App but the problem is some times it runs and most of the time it through the error (**libcore.io.IoBridge**)

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String inputLine;
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = null;

            clientSocket = new Socket(LOCAL_ADDRESS, PORT);

            Log.d("ExecuteService", (clientSocket.isConnected() ? "Connected" : "Not Connected"));

            writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),true);
            writer.println(cmd);
            writer.flush();
            Log.d("ExecuteService", "Lineis in:" + cmd);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("ExecuteService", "Lines :" + inputLine);
            }

            Log.d("ExecuteService", "Lineis out:" + cmd);

            writer.close();
            writer = null;
            in.close();
            in = null;
            clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            for(StackTraceElement st : exception.getStackTrace())
                Log.d("ExecuteService", st.toString());
        }

    }
```

Can any one please let me know how n when this error gets occur?